# Musical representation of pi

Tags: c#, math, audio, pi

I'm creating a program to output the values of pi as sound. I've seen a few videos and some other representations, and want to try to make my own for fun, except I'm unsure how to proceed.

There are the notes `A,B,C,D,E,F` and `G`.

Unfortunately, there are 10 possible values for a digit, `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, or 0`. I read something about a rule of fifths, but I am unsure how I would map the 10 numbers to sound. I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question.

How would you go about mapping a sound to numbers 0-9? I'd like to keep the spread as even as possible, so if every possible sound was on a line, 0-9 would be evenly distributed on the line, if that makes sense.

Currently, I'm trying `Console.beep(note frequency, 1000)` with these frequencies `http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html`, and ignoring values that aren't 1-7. Any thoughts?

Comment: "10 possible values for a digit"... in base 10. ;)

Comment: @MeirionHughes makes a good point. You could convert from base 10 to base 12 and then assign each of the semitones a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you consider the digits to be degrees of a scale rather than absolute note mappings?

In the key of C, as an example:

```
c = 1 // tonic or root
d = 2
e = 3 // third (major in this case)
f = 4
g = 5 // perfect fifth
a = 6
b = 7
c = 8 //octave
d = 9
```

As for the handling of 0 you could treat this as a rest.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil that's the basic point.  Those degrees of the scale are also able to be expressed as frequency (or as interval, the difference between frequencies).

Comment: I removed my comment because it was so obvious. Since you already replied - I said "I like this because you can easily change the key by changing the root note."

Answer (score 4):

You either need to assign two extra notes to the two spare numbers or represent the digits with something else, how about a rest or an accent for a note or some other effect?
Or of course you could include **semi tones**, you would have to miss one out though as there are 11 in an octave, or 12 including the octave (up or down) of the first note.
The nicest sounding thing would be assign each digit to a note on a scale like [E minor pentatonic](https://www.basicmusictheory.com/e-minor-pentatonic-scale), or [G major](https://www.basicmusictheory.com/g-major-scale) or a sweet bluesy one or something.
Example blues scale in **C minor**:

> 0 = C      //This is the root note
>  
>   1 = E flat
>  2 = F
>  3 = G
>   flat
>  4 = G 
>  5 = B flat
>  6 = C      //This note is one octave
>   higher than the root note
>  7 = E flat
>  8 = F
>  9 = G flat

**G  flat** in this scale is the *blues* note.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 8 to go up an octave, 9 to go down an octave and 0 for rest (silence).
Just a suggestion.
This will give variety to your song.

Hop this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

When all of the sharps and flats are included, the western musical scale has 12 semitones. To move from one semitone to the next, you multiply the frequency by the twelfth root of 2 (which is 1.05946).

It might be interesting to invent a 10 semitone scale, where the next semitone is found by multiplying by the **tenth** root of 2 (which is 1.0718). Then map the digits to these ten semitones, and off we go...